# How to send a string from cpp to a textbox defined in a winform header

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winforms, oop

i'm a pure c developer, with a task that needs a GUI, so I had to move to c++ for it (visual studio 2019).

a very simple problem, which drives me crazy...

in the cpp file i have values that changes overtime. those values need to be shown in a rich text box defined at the winform h. file.

my failed attempt is as follows:

calling the function in the cpp file:

```
insertText(logText);
```

The function itself:

```
void insertText(System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox^ logText)
{
    logText->Text = "%f" + range;
}
```

The function in the .h file:

```
public: System::Void logText_TextChanged(System::Object^ 
sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {

}
```

coming from C, Object Oriented is not my "cup of tea", so please excuse me for my basic knowledge.

the error is that "identifier txtLog is undefined.

i was asked to explain what I mean by "values that changes overtime":

the a physical sensor detects if intruder is entering the secured perimeter. a query that is sent by my c program to the sensor each second, answered with reply - "everything is ok" or with range and azimuth.

each time there is a detection of intruder i need to pass the range and azimuth to the logTxt.

Comment: Are you trying to append text or replace the existing? To append text (since you're using C++/CLI), you can write `logText->AppendText(range.ToString() + "\n");` (if `range` is not already a string). It's not clear how the `TextChanged` event is involved here. This event is raised when you change the Text of a Control. *i have values that change overtime*: how? Using  a Timer, other kind of events generated by something else?

Comment: Dear Jimi, thank you for your comment. i would like to append to a new line. can you direct me where i need to insert the code in your comment ? also, as said, the error comes from the function calling  insertText(logText)  which is in the cpp file. the changes of the value is upon detection of intruder. if the intruder detected the calculation of range and azimuth are done, and then, my intention was to update the logTxt with the new variables (range and azimuth)

Comment: You can also write `logText->AppendText(String::Format("{0}\n", range));` or `logText->AppendText(range + "\n");` if these look better :). -- You need to describe the error you have, what this `.cpp` file is used for. It's quite probable that, from where you're trying to call `insertText(logText);`, nobody knows about `logText` or its Form container class). Give some context to your question. What does *the values change over time* means, in practice. How/when that happens. Add these details to your question, not in comments.

Comment: Thank you Jimi. you have summed it up right - "nobody knows about logText". regarding the context, i described it in my answer to your comment.

Comment: Yes, right, that's what you do, the *How* you do it is still missing. Is this `.cpp` a class, does it contain static methods (you may have noticed that static method and instance members don't get along that well out of the box). How do you receive these notifications, do you have callbacks there? What do these look like? -- You may also have noticed that in your *entry point* (void main() in `[Project].cpp`) you have `Application::Run(gcnew [NameSpace]::SomeForm());`. The instance of that Form can be passed to another class. Add `#include "SomeForm.h"` to your `.cpp` *file*...

Comment: Add a public method that receives the instance of the Form that you store in a Field (check whether the instance is still valid before you use it after. See the `IsDisposed` and `IsHandleCreated` properties). Also add a public method to `SomeForm.h`: you'll be calling this method when you have new data to show in the RichTextBox. The public method in `SomeForm.h` takes the value you passed in and shows it in the RichTextBox. Don't try to change the RTB text from your callbacks(?) directly.

Comment: Thanks Jimi. cpp is not a class. As i told you im coming from pure c, and only using c++ for GUI. I will try to understand what you meant in your last comment, OOP is not something that i am much familiar with, especially in c++